# Saving a block as an object to a variable without defining a function in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, proc

I'm looking into blocks at the moment, and they have stumped me.

I used this as an example:

```
class ProcExample
  attr_reader :proc_class
  def initialize(&block)
    @stored_proc = block
    @proc_class = @stored_proc.class
  end
  def use_proc(arg)
    @stored_proc.call(arg)
  end
end

eg = ProcExample.new {|t| puts t}
p eg.proc_class
p eg.use_proc("Whoooooooo")
```

Now I kind of (not really( understand how the block is passed into @stored_proc. I used @proc_class because I was curious what class the block object was actually stored as.

But what if I wanted to store a block in a regular variable?

E.g.:

```
block_object = {|param| puts param**2}
```

But I found that this is treated as a Hash and not a block/proc. Naturally an error arises. I've tried assigning it with an ampersand in the variable name, and at the beginning of the block but that doesn't work.

Eventually I was wondering if it was possible to call a function and replace the block with a variable containing the block.

Like so:

```
(1..10).each block_object
```

Is this possible in Ruby?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot assign blocks to a variable.

Blocks aren't really objects. They are special syntax for passing code to a higher-order method. If you want a piece of executable code that you can assign to a variable, pass around and manipulate, you need to use a `Proc` object.

There are two kinds of `Proc`s: lambdas and regular procs. They behave differently in two aspects: argument binding semantics and `return` semantics. lambdas bind arguments like methods and `return` returns from the lambda, just like `return` in a method returns from the method. Regular procs bind arguments like blocks and `return` returns from the enclosing method, not the proc, just like `return` in a block.

Regular procs can be created by passing a block to `Proc.new` or alternatively to `Kernel#proc`. Lambdas can be created by passing a block to `Kernel#lambda` or with the "stabby lambda" literal syntax:

```
lambda_object = ->param { puts param**2 }
```

In order to convert `Proc`s to blocks and the other way around, Ruby has the unary prefix `&` modifier. This modifier is only valid in parameter lists and argument lists. When used in a *parameter* list, it means "wrap the block in a proc and bind it to this variable". When used in an *argument* list. it means "unwrap this proc into a block (and if it's not a proc already, call `to_proc` on it first) and pass it as a block argument".

```
(1..10).each(&lambda_object)
```

I'm surprised that you haven't already seen the unary prefix `&` modifier used in this way, it is actually fairly common, e.g. in something like `['1', '2'].map(&:to_s)`.

*Another* kind of object that also represents a piece of executable code is a `Method` object. It supports some of the same interface as `Proc`s do, in particular `#call`, `#to_proc`, `#arguments`, `#arity` etc. There are two ways to get a `Method` object: either grab a method that is bound to a receiver from that receiver using the `Object#method` method or grab an `UnboundMethod` object from a class or module (e.g. using `Module#instance_method`) and bind it to a receiver using `UnboundMethod#bind` which will return a `Method` object.

Since `Method` implements `to_proc`, you can pass it to a method as a block using the unary prefix `&` modifier, e.g.:

```
# Warning: extremely silly example :-)

ary = []

(1..10).each(&ary.method(:<<))

ary
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

ary = []

(1..10).each(&Array.instance_method(:<<).bind(ary))

ary
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Wow thank you Jorg for taking all of that time out of your day to explain this to me. Much appreciated! How did you get so knowledgeable on the intricacies of the language?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a proc object, I believe.

```
block = proc { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a proc or lambda. There are some subtle differences between them; and between Ruby versions. A good overview can been seen here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBC-G6hahWA given by Peter Cooper